# JPA/Hibernate ClassCastException only occurring in certain environments

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-security, classcastexception

I have some JPA code (with Hibernate as the provider) that is throwing the dreaded ClassCastException.  However, it only seems to be occurring on certain computers and not others with the exact same codebase, configuration, database schema and data.  Has anybody else encountered this?  Is there a way to resolve it?  I am fairly certain it is not a bug in my code since it is working in certain environments (on development machines that are newer Macbook Pros) but not in others (a Mac Mini and an Amazon Linux AMI).

For reference, this shows up when trying to authenticate a user through Spring Security using digest authentication.   Spring is configured to retrieve the list of users by calling a bean that implements the UserDetailsService interface:

```
@Component("httpDigestUserDetailsService")
public class HttpDigestUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpDigestUserDetailsService.class);

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    List<User> users = userService.findBy("username", username);
    User user = users.get(0);
    return new HttpDigestUserDetails(user);
}
```

The error occurs when calling `userService.findBy()`.  `UserService` is implemented by `UserServiceImpl` as follows:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class UserServiceImpl extends AbstractService<User> implements UserService {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    public Class getPersistentObjectClass() {
        return User.class;
    }

    public void signUp(User user) {
        user.addUserRole(UserRole.ROLE_USER);
        save(user);
    }
}
```

And the real `findBy` method is implemented in `AbstractRestService`:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public abstract class AbstractService<T extends PO> implements EntityService<T> {
    public List<T> findBy(String ... fields) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (int i=0; i<fields.length - 1; i+=2) {
            map.put(fields[i], fields[i+1]);
        }
        return findBy(map);
    }

    public List<T> findBy(Map<String, Object> fields) {
        String queryString = String.format("SELECT o FROM %s o", getPersistentObjectClass().getName());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Set<String> fieldsSet = fields.keySet();
        boolean first = true;

        for (String fieldName : fieldsSet) {
            if (first) { sb.append(" WHERE "); first = false; } else sb.append(" AND ");
            sb.append(String.format("o.%s = :%s", fieldName, fieldName));
        }
        queryString = queryString + sb.toString();

        TypedQuery<T> q = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString, getPersistentObjectClass());
        for (String fieldName : fieldsSet) {
            q.setParameter(fieldName, fields.get(fieldName));
        }

        List<T> results = q.getResultList();
        return results;
    }
}
```

The `User` domain object is annotated as follows (omitting getters/setters that are just simple properties:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends PO {

    private Patient patient;
    private Provider provider;
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id", nullable = true)
    public Patient getPatient() {
        return Patient;
    }

    public void setPatient(Patient patient) {
        this.patient = patient;
    }


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id", nullable = true)
    public Provider getProvider() {
        return provider;
    }

    public void setProvider() {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }
}
```

And finally, the `PO` base object that all domain objects extend:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class PO implements Serializable {
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

`Patient` and `Provider` also extend PO, and have inverse mappings back to User.  I can add that code if it would be helpful to see it.

Finally, here is the exception and stack trace I receive:

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of PO.id; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of PO.id

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@7e46a468
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:164)
org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:341)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4491)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4213)
org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:209)
org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$8.noCascade(CascadingAction.java:375)
org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:176)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:160)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:151)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:88)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1213)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:402)
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:512)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:394)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
com.luminatehealth.service.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2a6af235.findBy(<generated>)
com.luminatehealth.rest.security.HttpDigestUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(HttpDigestUserDetailsService.java:33)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DigestAuthenticationFilter.java:144)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

I've read about issues with Hibernate relating to how Proxy objects are created when loading domain objects that extend from a shared superclass, but most of the advice I've seen says you should ensure you put your annotations on the properties and not the fields (which we're already doing), or use eager loading to avoid proxies being created (all our associations use eager loading already).  I'm also confused as to why proxies are being created at all, as I thought that only occurs when you need to lazy load associations.  I'm assuming it has something to do with transaction management in this case.

I've been banging my head against the wall on this for two days now with little progress, so I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar problem, did you manage to solve it?  If so please post an answer